# NodeJs. Вставка в монго сразу после удаления

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Хочу выполнить очень простое действие: очистить коллекцию и вставить в нее пачку данных, однако уже в течении нескольких дней ничего не выходит, прошу помощи.
Изначально пробовал с помощью mongoose:

```
model.remove({}, (err, docs) => {
if (err) {
    console.log('remove error');
} else {
    console.log('remove success');
    model.insertMany(seeds, (insertError, insertedRecords) => {
        if (insertError) {
            console.log('insert error');
        } else {
            console.log('insert success');
        }
    });
}
});
```

Вижу на консоли только `remove success`.
Потом пробовал с помощью драйвера:

```
model.collection.remove((removeError, removeResult) => {
   console.log('remove cb');
   model.collection.insert(seeds, (insertError, insertedRecords) => {
       console.log('insert cb');
   });
});
```

Также вижу только `remove cb`

Mongoose схема такая:

```
const schema = new Schema({
   name: {type: String, unique: true, index: true},
});
```

Вставляемые данные:

```
export default [
   {name: 'USA'},
   {name: 'Germany'},
   {name: 'France'}, ...
```

**UPDATE1**

Попробовал `async.js`, результат тот же:

```
    async.series([
    (cb) => {
        console.log('remove serie');
        model.remove({}, (err) => {
            console.log('remove cb');
            cb(err);
        });
    },
    (cb) => {
        console.log('insert serie');
        model.insertMany(seeds, (err) => {
            console.log('insert cb');
            cb(err);
        });
    }
], (err) => {
    console.log('err');
});
```

В консоли `remove serie` `remove cb` `insert serie`

Comment: async.series - сначала одно действие, потом другое. Даже "серии" не будет: массив из одной функции удаления и вставка в коллбэке. Стандартная альтернатива - Promise: результат (пустая коллекция) передаётся аргументом в resolve(...)  и в .then(... => снова обращение к коллекции (уже пустой) и вставка в неё новых данных. Хотя, лучше даже async.parallel - по завершении удаления в коллбэк ничего не передаётся а она просто вызывается - в ней просто добавление новых данных. Всё дело в двух раздельных обращениях к коллекции (а не одно в другом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коллекции были Бобик и Шарик - зашёл прямо в базу данных (в FAR) и убедился.
Поправил этот код, вот так:

```
var async = require('async');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Dogs = require('./models/Dogs');

var arrDogs = [{ name: 'Барбос', slug: 'barbos', age: 8 },
                { name: 'Букет', slug: 'buket', age: 7 }];

async.parallel([
function(callback) {
    Dogs.remove({}, (err) => {
        if(err) console.error(err);
    });
    callback();
}], () => {
            Dogs.insertMany(arrDogs, (err, data) => {
                if(err) console.error(err);
                console.log(data);
            });
            mongoose.disconnect();
        });
```

Запустил, в консоль Sublime Text написала:

```
[ { __v: 0,
name: 'Барбос',
slug: 'barbos',
age: 8,
_id: 58e0af2c0bfd730f0868fc64 },
  { __v: 0,
name: 'Букет',
slug: 'buket',
age: 7,
_id: 58e0af2c0bfd730f0868fc65 } ]
```

[Finished in 1.0s]

И даже (что уж и лишнее) пошёл в базу - там теперь другие два документа: Барбос и Букет.

Comment: Я удалил 3 ваших ответа. Пожалуйста, перенесите все ценное из них в один ответ.